# Getting incorrect values when using dgsev in C

Tags: c, linear-regression, lapack

I am using the dgesv library in C to do linear regression (with intercept) and return the regression coefficients. I know that, given the values X and Y in the code below, I should get regression coefficients of:

```
The regression coefficients: 26.851352 0.240842 0.119026
```

However, when I run my code, I get regression coefficients of:

```
The regression coefficients: 10680696.608794, 112946.210120, -188705.310886
```

I believe that my matrix multiplications are working (when debugging). Is there anything I am missing that is causing my regression coefficient values to be so large and incorrect?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 16
#define P 2
void dgesv_(int *M, int *NRHS, double *A, int *LDA, int *IPIV, double *B, int *LDB, int *INFO);

int main(){
/* longley dataset from R: Employed (Y) GNP.deflator and Population (X) */
double Y[N] = {60.323,61.122,60.171,61.187,63.221,63.639,64.989,63.761,66.019,67.857,68.169,66.513,68.655,69.564,69.331,70.551};
double X[N*(P+1)] = {1.0,83.0,107.608,1.0,88.5,108.632,1.0,88.2,109.773,1.0,89.5,110.929,1.0,96.2,112.075,1.0,98.1,113.27,1.0,99.0,115.094,1.0,100.0,116.219,1.0,101.2,117.388,1.0,104.6,118.734,1.0,108.4,120.445,1.0,110.8,121.95,1.0,112.6,123.366,1.0,114.2,125.368,1.0,115.7,127.852,1.0,116.9,130.081};

int i;
int j;
int k;

int n = P+1;
int nrhs = 1;
double XTX[(P+1)*(P+1)];
int lda = P+1;
int ipiv[P+1];
double XTY[P+1];
int ldb = P+1;
int info;

/* Matrix multiplication */
for (i=0; i<(P+1); i++){
    for (j=0; j<(P+1); j++){
        XTX[i*(P+1)+j]=0;
        for (k=0; k<N; k++){
            XTX[i*(P+1)+j] += X[(P+1)*k+i] * X[(P+1)*k+j];
        }
    }
}

/* Matrix multiplication */
for (i=0; i<(P+1); i++){
    XTY[i] = 0;
    for (j=0; j<N; j++){
        XTY[i] += X[(P+1)*j+1] * Y[j];
    }
}

dgesv_(&n, &nrhs, XTX, &lda, ipiv, XTY, &ldb, &info);

/* From docoumentation, the regression coefficients are returned in XTY */
printf("The regression coefficients: %f, %f, %f\n", XTY[0], XTY[1], XTY[2]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's `dgesv` from LAPACK, right? You might want to note which version of LAPACK you're using, too, just in case it's relevant. At least it would make your code easier to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second matrix multiplication seems incorrect:

```
    XTY[i] += X[(P+1)*j+1] * Y[j];
```

Why do you add `1` ?  Should it not be:

```
    XTY[i] += X[(P+1)*j] * Y[j];
```